# Create a GeoDataFrame with more than one geo_column

Tags: python, postgis, geopandas, geodataframe

I am working with PostgreSQL/PostGIS and geopandas. I have tables with more than one geometry.

How can I move this kind of tables to geopandas recognizing all the geometries columns? I am using `GeoDataFrame.from_postgis` but I can only specify one column with geometry.

Comment: Have you tried to detach both geometries columns in different geodataframes and then make a spatial join?
This way maybe you can get a multipolygon geodataframe.

Comment: Geopandas can have only one active geometry per row. However, you can have more, they'll just be GeoSeries stored as an attribute. If you want to use all columns as active geometries, you will have to split your table to keep one geometry per row and than join them together. Spatial join doesn't make a lot of sense to me in this case.